# Putting Filters with parameters directly causes error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-7

So, i have been trying to add unique token filter with parameters without creating a separate token filter in my custom analyzer.

According to documentation an example of token filter with parameters without creating a separate token filter:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html#analysis-length-tokenfilter-analyze-ex

According to documentation an example of token filter with parameters without creating a separate token filter:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html

```
PUT pokemon
{
  "settings": 
  {
    "analysis": 
    {
      "analyzer": 
      {
        "deba_analyzer": 
        {
          "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": ["lowercase","stop","kstem",{"type": "unique","only_on_same_position": true}]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": 
  {
    "properties": 
    {
      "name": 
      {
        "type":"text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, cutting to the chase, its giving me error:

```
"reason" : "Failed to load settings from [{\"analysis\":{\"analyzer\":{\"deba_analyzer\":{\"filter\":[{\"only_on_same_position\":true,\"type\":\"unique\"}],\"char_filter\":[\"html_strip\"],\"tokenizer\":\"uax_url_email\"}}}}]",
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
  "reason" : "only value lists are allowed in serialized settings"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the token filter link you've attached specified the `unique` filter under separate `filter` definitions and you'll need to do the same. In other words, the analyzer's `filter` array accepts only

1. names of built-in filters with default settings
2. or names of custom filters which need to be defined separately.

So use this:

```
PUT pokemon
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "deba_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "kstem",
            "my_unique_filter"                <--
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_unique_filter": {                 <--
          "type": "unique",
              "only_on_same_position": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "analyzer": "deba_analyzer",          <--
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And don't forget to specify your meticulously created analyzer -- if you don't it's going to be registered but not applied to any of your fields.

---

EDIT

The `_analyze` API from your example does allow specifying the filters verbosely but the `PUT` API simply does not.